# Installing chartjs in project without npm, bower or CDN

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working on a graph page for a project and my client does not want me to use npm, bower or CDN. so my question is how would I use the **chartjs** library without using these options?

I tried using it this way:

```
var Chart = require(['../chartjs/Chart.js']);
var ctx = document.getElementById("bar-chart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

but I keep getting the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Script error for "../chartjs/Chart.js".`

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import chart from './chart';
console.log(chart);
```

Comment: @TanDoung  I tried this but now the function that i want to use chartjs in becomes not defined.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: FFWDChart is not defined

Comment: Do you try to use <script> tag http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#script-tag?

Comment: yea i tried that turns out i made a typo there last time i did.